# How to filter blocked emails in gmail

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, gmail-labels

Because I don't want to lose any email I have this filter on my gmail which bypasses google's original spam filtering:

```
Matches: is:spam
Do this: Never send it to Spam
```

However, I have a block list that I would like to apply a filter on. Something like this:

```
Matches: is:blocked
Do this: Delete
```

It doesn't work on gmail though.

Comment: Do you mean that you blocked some senders but the messages from them still appear in your inbox? That looks like a Gmail bug.

Comment: No it is not a gmail bug as I applied the first filter myself. The first filter bypasses the gmail original spam filter. My problem is that, now all emails in the block list goes to the inbox so I need to somehow add another filter (something like the second one) to redirect the block list to the spam.

Answer (score -1):

Apparently there is no search term in gmail to capture the block list

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit or, even better, find a reference backing this up?